# метод для java collections

Tags: java, коллекции

помогите написать правильное if условие 
суть в том что метод принимает String значение и если такое же значение есть в 'ячейки' коллекции то  он должен выдать эту ячейку,не могу никак понять как написать правильно этот метод!
заранее огромное спасибо!

```
 List<String> myList = new ArrayList<>();


public void addBook(Book book) {
    myList.add("Author: "+book.getAuthor()+" Title: "+book.getTitle());
}
public void removeBook(Book book){
    myList.remove("Author: "+book.getAuthor()+" Title: "+book.getTitle());
}

public void getBookByTitle(String title){

    for(int i=0;i<myList.size();i++){
            if(title.equals(myList.){
            System.out.println( );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (myList.get(i).contains(" Title: " + title))
{
```

---

```
if (myList.get(i).endsWith(" Title: " + title))
{
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!